# Dynamclly loading menus in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically change the array I am sending to map so through a prop so I can change the menus.

> menus.js

```
export const menu1 = [
    "menu_item1",
    "menu_item2"
];

export const menu2 = [
    "menu_item1",
    "menu_item2"
];
```

> app.js

```
import {menu1, menu2} from "menus";

.
.
.
.

// after clicking on a button we will receive a  string "menu2" and set it to represent the menu2 object.

this.setState = {
   network_menu: menu2
}
```

I tried doing this with eval but no luck there as well

- bonus question, how do I export all those arrays from above in one time? I tried  * but didn't work

Thanks!

Comment: You should set the state like this: `this.setState({network_menu: menu2})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exporting multiple menus at the same time you can do something like this:

```js
export const menus = {
  menu1: [
    "menu_item1",
    "menu_item2"
  ],
  menu2: [
    "menu_item1",
    "menu_item2"
  ]
}
```

And your app.js would change like:

```js
import {
  menus
} from "menus";

.
.
.
.

// after clicking on a button we will receive a  string "menu2" and set it to represent the menu2 object.

this.setState({
  network_menu: menu2 //use menus.menu2
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I did this earlier but i was missing the object and inside of it arrays I did it the other way around now all works great! thanks